# Kou model implementation Python

Tags: option-pricing, programming

Hey I try to implement Kou model in Python. This is my code:

```
def Hh(n,x):
    if n<-1: return 0
    elif n==-1:
        return np.exp(-x**2/2)
    elif n==0:
        return math.sqrt(2*np.pi)*scs.norm.cdf(-x)
    else:
        return (Hh(n-2,x)-x*Hh(n-1,x))/n


def P(n,k):
    if k<1 or n<1: return 0
    elif n==k:
        return p**n
    else:
        suma=0
        i=k
        while i<=n-1:
            suma=suma+sc.special.binom(n-k-1, i-k)*sc.special.binom(n, i)*(n_1/(n_1+n_2))**(i-k)*(n_2/(n_1+n_2))**(n-i)*p**i*q**(n-i)
            i+=1
        return suma


def Q(n,k):
if k<1 or n<1: return 0
elif n==k:
    return q**n
else:
    suma=0
    i=k
    while i<=n-1:
        suma=suma+sc.special.binom(n-k-1, i-k)*sc.special.binom(n, i)*(n_1/(n_1+n_2))**(n-i)*(n_2/(n_1+n_2))**(i-k)*p**(n-i)*q**i
        i+=1
    return suma

def Pi(n):
    return (np.exp(-lam*T)*(lam*T)**n)/math.factorial(n)


def I(n,c,a,b,d):
    if b>0 and a!=0:
        suma=0
        i=0
        while i<=n:
            suma=suma+(b/a)**(n-i)*Hh(i,b*c-d)
            i+=1
        return -(np.exp(a*c)/a)*suma+(b/a)**(n+1)*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)/b)*np.exp((a*d/b)+(a**2/(2*b**2)))*scs.norm.cdf(-b*c+d+a/b)
    elif b<0 and a<0:
        suma=0
        i=0
        while i<=n:
            suma=suma+(b/a)**(n-i)*Hh(i,b*c-d)
            i+=1
        return -(np.exp(a*c)/a)*suma-(b/a)**(n+1)*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)/b)*np.exp((a*d/b)+(a**2/(2*b**2)))*scs.norm.cdf(b*c-d-a/b)
    else: return 0


def Y(mu,sigma,lam,p, n_1, n_2, a ,T):
    n=1
    suma1=0
    suma2=0
    while n<=10:
        k=1
        suma_1=0
        while k<=n:
            suma_1=suma_1+P(n,k)*(sigma*np.sqrt(T)*n_1)**k*I(k-1,a-mu*T,-n_1, -1/(sigma*np.sqrt(T)), -sigma*n_1*np.sqrt(T))
            k+=1
        suma1=suma1+Pi(n)*suma_1
        n+=1
    n=1
    while n<=10:
        k=1
        suma_2=0
        while k<=n:
            suma_2=suma_2+Q(n,k)*(sigma*np.sqrt(T)*n_2)**k*I(k-1,a-mu*T,n_2, 1/(sigma*np.sqrt(T)), -sigma*n_2*np.sqrt(T))
            k+=1
        suma2=suma2+Pi(n)*suma_2
        n+=1
    return np.exp((sigma*n_1)**2*T/2)/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi*T))*suma1+np.exp((sigma*n_2)**2*T/2)/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi*T))*suma2+Pi(0)*scs.norm.cdf(-(a-mu*T)/(sigma*np.sqrt(T)))


def Kou(r,sigma,lam,p,n_1,n_2,S_0,K,T):
    zeta=p*n_1/(n_1-1)+(1-p)*n_2/(n_2+1)-1
    lam2=lam*(zeta+1)
    n_12=n_1-1
    n_22=n_2+1
    p2=p/(1+zeta)*n_1/(n_1-1)
    return S_0*Y(r+1/2*sigma**2-lam*zeta,sigma,lam2,p2,n_12,n_22,math.log(K/S_0),T)-K*np.exp(-r*T)*Y(r-1/2*sigma**2-lam*zeta,sigma,lam,p,n_1,n_2,math.log(K/S_0),T)
```

and use following data (from Kou 2002)

```
S_0=100
sigma=0.16
r=0.05
lam=1
n_1=10
n_2=5
T=0.5
K=98
p=0.4
```

Unfortunately, my result is 6.25, when in Kou should be 9.14732. Can someone check if my code is OK, or if someone has code of Kou model, would he be able to give several values ​​for different functions so I can check in which function I have mistake?

Comment: Kou (2002, Footnote 9) says that’s enough to truncate the infinite sum at $n=10$ or $n=15$. I can confirm this from experimental testing. So you can reduce the number of iterations :)

Comment: I change from $100$ to $10$ but I get result $0$. Something is wrong :(

Comment: @KeSchn do you use Kou model? Can you  tell me what values for different functions (for example `Y`) you get from your code? It would help me to find mistake in my code, because now I have no Idea what is wrong.

Comment: I get $\Upsilon(0)=0.5932182$. Can you check if my result from Hh function is correct? For example I have $\text{Hh}_3(2)=0.002274327253198013$ and $\text{Hh}_7(-2)=0.9201042657946543$.

Comment: it's weird. What result do you have for $Hh_5(-4)$? I have $36.01189$ and it is correct result (figure 2 Kou 2002) so I think that my $Hh$ function is well defined. Can you check if you have the same result. Do you get a correct result ($9.14732$) when you use the data from Kou 2002 footnote 9?

Comment: Yes, I do get the same result as Kou (2002, Footnote 9): $9.1473$. However, I just checked my Hh function. I do get $\mathrm{Hh}_3(2)=0.0023$, $\mathrm{Hh}_7(-2)=0.9201$ and $\mathrm{Hh}_5(-4)=36.0119$. In fact, some further updated numbers: $\Upsilon(0)=0.6407$, $\Upsilon(-0.5)=0.9840$ and $\Upsilon(0.5) = 0.0112$ (for $n=10$, $T=0.5$, $\mu=0.12$, $\sigma=0.2$, $\lambda=1$, $\eta_+=10$, $\eta_-=5$, $p=0.4$).

Comment: using the data provided by you, I have following results from diferent functions: $P_{5,2}=0.05831$, $Q_{5,2}=0.189866$, $I_5(2,2,2,2)=0.001801522$, $I_5(-2,-2,-2,-2)=0.27965218$. Can you give your results?

Comment: I have $Q_{5,2}=0.1899$ and $P_{5,2}=0.0583$. Furthermore, I get $I_5(2,2,2,2)=0.0018$ and $I_5(-2,-2,-2,-2)=0.2797$. They look very much like your numbers.

Comment: @KeSchn So my $\Upsilon$ function must be incorrect. Could you share with me your code of this function or check my code? I can't find a mistake in my code :(

Comment: I don't have pyhton code for the Kou model. I'm sorry. But it should be easy to find the error now that you know where it is.Just check it by hand for the first few iterations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112070/discussion-between-mr-price-and-keschn).

Comment: Could you find the error or shall I add some context (equations) to the function below?

Comment: I get corret result $9.14$ (for data from Kou 2002)! BUT you write that  $\Upsilon(0)=0.6407$ for data that you provide but when I use your data I get  $\Upsilon(0)=0.593218$  Are you sure that you use exactly the same data that you write?

Comment: Sorry, yes of course. I get $\Upsilon(0)=0.5932$. Bloody hell, must've been yet another typo in my comment. I'm so sorry. The code below yields $\Upsilon(0)=0.5932$. So, you're right. Well done!

Comment: @KeSchn do you now where can I found full solution of Kou SDE?

Comment: Please have a look at [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/25062/solution-of-mertons-jump-diffusion-sde)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this matlab function help?

The expression for $\Upsilon$ (`Y`) is split up in three parts. The infinite sum is truncated after 10 iterations (`bound`). We already compared our results for `PFunction`, `QFunction` and `IFunction`.

```
function Y = Upsilon(x,T,mu,sigma,lambda,etaplus,etaminus,p,q)

    bound = 10;
    
    pi0 = exp(-lambda*T);
    pin = exp(-lambda*T) .*(lambda*T).^(1:bound)./factorial(1:bound);
    
    sump1 = zeros(bound,1);
    sumq1 = zeros(bound,1);
    
    for n=1:bound
        sump2 = zeros(n,1);
        sumq2 = zeros(n,1);
        for k=1:n
            sump2(k) = PFunction(n,k,p,q,etaplus,etaminus) * (sigma*sqrt(T)*etaplus)^k * IFunction(-etaplus,-1/(sigma*sqrt(T)),x-mu*T,-sigma*etaplus*sqrt(T),k-1);
            sumq2(k) = QFunction(n,k,p,q,etaplus,etaminus) * (sigma*sqrt(T)*etaminus)^k * IFunction(etaminus,1/(sigma*sqrt(T)),x-mu*T,-sigma*etaminus*sqrt(T),k-1);
        end
       sump1(n) = pin(n)*sum(sump2);
       sumq1(n) = pin(n)*sum(sumq2);
    end
    
    Y(1) = exp((sigma*etaplus)^2*T/2)/(sigma*sqrt(2*pi*T)) * sum(sump1);
    Y(2) = exp((sigma*etaminus)^2*T/2)/(sigma*sqrt(2*pi*T)) * sum(sumq1);
    Y(3) = pi0*normcdf(-(x-mu*T)/(sigma*sqrt(T)));
    Y = sum(Y);
    
end
```

Comment: Can I ask you how do you calibrate Kou model? It's 5 parameters to estimate and it takes a long time.

Comment: Simply ask Python to find the parameters which minimise the sum of squared errors. This shouldn’t take too long if you follow best practices and write the code efficiently. You should use reasonable initial guesses (look at Kou’s papers).

Comment: Ok thanks, I wil try and probably improve my code becuase now it takes a looong time :D

Comment: is it normal that from calibration I get $\lambda=50$ and $p=1$ and $\eta_1=50$, $\eta_2=155$? Are these values ​​not too high? You write that I should use reasonable initial guesses but in which paper they are given?

Comment: @Mr.Price Sorry, fully forgot to come back to you. The numbers are completely off. Something is going wrong. Have a look at how to implement ``calibration''. Your implementation my be wrong? You should simply minimise the sum of squared (relative) errors between your model and the market. The market quotes should be free of arbitrage of course.

Comment: Now I get values:$ [0.453, 1.340, 0.150, 3.628, 3.194]$ for $\sigma, \lambda,p, \eta_1, \eta_2$ respectively. Is it okay? What are "normal" values for these parameters?

Comment: Looks much better :) These values look reasonable I guess. Just compare your numbers to other published papers that used the Kou model

Comment: Could you help me? I am 99% sure that my code for model calibration is OK. Unfortunatey when I calibrate Black Scholes, Merton, Kou, CGMY ang VG model to my data I gets very disappointing results, i.e. the RMSE for all models is very similar and there is not much improvement over the BS model. I think that my data is OK. Could I send you the data to calibrate these models and we compare the results? Or maybe you will send me your data and I will calibrate the models. Then I would know if my code is OK. Please help me if you can